# Are Activities visible if related to records visible via Sharing Sets?

Tags: community, activities, partner-communities, sharing-sets

We have a Partner Community where Opportunities are shared via Sharing Sets. Users log activities against those sharing sets. Note that this isn't to do with the Public field on Activity.

We've noticed that users can't see activities if they aren't the "assigned to" or the owner of the records in the Who or What fields. We suspect this is because users are not getting access via record ownership, role hierarchy, sharing rules etc. but through Sharing Sets which is more run time. Though this works in other areas (e.g. Master/Detail relationships), those aren't polymorphic fields, so I imagine there's additional complexity there that means this doesn't always work.

Has anybody encountered this before? Or maybe the opposite - do you have this setup working, and can you tell me I have gotten something wrong somewhere else?

Even ideas about ways to validate this (or not) are welcome...

Comment: Is there a a reason you're using sharing set instead of sharing rules?  I know this will work with sharing rules.  I've run into undocumented limitations with sharing sets (unrelated to what you are doing) and I feel they are weak workaround for sharing rules

Comment: Scalability basically. Eventually, we'll have more partners than sharing rules will allow. Another minor niggle is that it's also more setup for each partner when they're onboarded. We could switch to sharing rules for now and hope this gets "fixed" in time. At the moment, it'd just be good to get confirmation. I'm off to post an idea as well.

Comment: I created an idea here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213287&language=en_US&type=1